# Broken border to QToolButton

Tags: css, qt, qtstylesheets

i need circle QToolButton with semi transparent color.
Problem is then i set QSS like this:

```
QToolButton#someButton
{
    border: 3px solid #50dd2d9a; // any semi transparent color to border
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

(the main fragment is border has any semi transparent color)

then border become broken like on image:
[Broken border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCxm9.png)

This border colors overlap each other.

If QToolButton has no border-radius then everything is okey.

What can be a problem?

Comment: Is the radius correct? I mean, is it exactly equal to the half of the width or height of the button? (less the thickness of the border). Maybe you should try setting a smaller number as the radius. My guess is that for optimization purposes, only one-eight of the circle is painted exactly, and the rest is just rotated and bit-blted. And if the radius is not exact, the bit-blted parts overlap and transparency gets broken.

Comment: @V.K.authorofHiFile Yes, i think qss can be work like that. But my button height = width = 40px. And for circle button i need border-radius: 20px;

Comment: I tried now use border-radius less then mine. It has same problem with overlap, but also it's became not circle, of course

Comment: Then you will probably need to override the class and paint it yourself in `paintEvent()`. Qt stylesheets are unfortunately a technology full of bugs which is not maintained any more. I would not advice using it or depending on it.

Comment: @V.K.authorofHiFile Got it, thank you